# How do I get a slack bot that is sending a message via Python to post @here and ping the channel?

Tags: python, slack

Currently my slack app / bot will post a message being sent via Python that has @here or @channel in the text but the @here or @channel won't be highlighted or actually ping the channel. Here is the code:

```
import slack
def slack_notif(slackchannel,message):
        client = slack.WebClient(token='xxxmytokenxxx')
        client.chat_postMessage(channel=slackchannel, text=message)
slack_notif(
        slackchannel = 'mychannel',
        message = '<@here> This is a test'
        )
```

Output = @here This is a test

[Intended output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2auaZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

To use **@here** & **@channel** as 'mentions',

they are marked as :

`<!here>`  &  `<!channel>`